# Can anyone give me a starting point to this Recursive Fractal?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I need to draw a H tree fractal using Turtle and recursive functions. I have a basic understanding of recursions but just can't seem to understand how to make the H tree. I can draw the H for level 1 which is just one H but after that I'm not sure on how to draw 4 more H shapes and so on.

H Tree image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't coded this up, but I'll try to explain how to do it.  The H-tree is a capital H with an H-tree half the size centered at each of the four points at the ends of its uprights.  So you a function something like

```
drawH(x, y, size)
```

Here x and y are the coordinate of the center of the crossbar, and size is say, the length of the crossbar.  Besides drawing the H, drawH will have four recursive calls, like

drawH(x1, y1, size/2)

where x1, y1 are the coordinates of one of the upright endpoints.  (I hope this is clear.  I wish I could draw a picture.)

There's a problem you may have noticed.  This never stops; it draws infinitely many aitches.  So we need another parameter:

```
drawH(x, y, size, level)
```

and the recursive calls become

```
drawH(x1, y1, size/2, level-1)
```

Now drawH doesn't do any drawing if level == 0.  It looks to me like you'll want level=3 in the initial call.

I hope this helps. One can do some amazing fractal drawings with turtle; have fun!